# How to embed a map into Netlogo using GIS extension?

Tags: gis, netlogo

The format of the map imported should be preferably ".shp" file.Also please tell how to create such a file. I have tried KML but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, vectors need to be .shp to be imported. You can create vector files in most GIS programs (ArcGIS, QGIS, etc) and export to .shp. Or there's online tools for converting KML to .shp (eg http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php)

Raster files need to be saved as .ASC or .GRD for use as a dataset in Netlogo.

Comment: Ayush: what have you tried? Have you looked at the GIS extension documentation and the GIS sample models in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library? If so, where did you get stuck?